# Shiny Data Table Column Names

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I have this Shiny app, where I'm including a bar plot and a data table of a database of cars, basically Makes (Toyota, BMW) with different models each.

I'm correctly displaying the barplot in frequency order, after choosing the Make in a Select Input (drop-down many), but when I want t display it in the data table, I'm unable to change the name of the columns. Also, column Y is the count of frequency.

I have seen that I can use de datatable(colnames), but on Shiny I don't have directly that function, I just have dataTableOutput() and renderDataTable.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("make_dec", 
                     label ="Select Make",
                     choices = c("TESLA", "AUDI", "NISSAN", "KIA", "CHEVROLET", "FIAT", "FORD",
                                 "BMW", "TOYOTA", "VOLVO", "MERCEDES-BENZ")
                     )
       ),

       # Show a plot of the generated distribution
       mainPanel(
          plotOutput("makePlot")
       )
       
       
       
   ),
   
   dataTableOutput('tabla')
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$makePlot <- renderPlot({
 
     evpd %>%   
       as.data.frame() %>%
       filter(Make == input$make_dec) %>%
       arrange(desc(Model)) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x=fct_infreq(Model), fill=Model)) +
       geom_bar() +
       theme(legend.position="bottom",
             axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90)) +
       labs(x="Models", y="Units",
            title="Car Models of each Make",
            subtitle="Each Make has its different models of vehicles"
            ) +
       scale_fill_hue(c=45, l=80)
     
   })

   output$tabla <- renderDataTable({
     
     evpd %>% filter(Make == input$make_dec) %>%
       count(Model)
   })
   
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any idea how to rename columns?

[image]

Comment: `evpd %>% filter(Make == input$make_dec) %>% summarise(Y = count(Model), .groups = “drop”)`.

Comment: Use the **DT** package to get the `datatable` function.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent After that, where should I put that function?

Comment: In `renderDT` (in server). And use `DTOutput` in the UI.

Comment: @Limey where should I enter the new column names?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent 

So, I would be replacing the renderDataTable() function with renderDT() function?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found.

```
  evpd %>%
  filter(Make == input$make_dec) %>%
  group_by(Make, Model) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  datatable(colnames=c("Make", "Model", "Units"))
```